# Where do I find the "the HTMLQuestion schema URL" and CDATA (newbie ... run out of options)

Tags: mechanicalturk

I want to conduct a simple turk survey.

I've made the form, uploaded the images and set the details but I'm not quite sure what's next.

**Here is the framework of my form with what I think are the AWS elements needed but:**

1) How do I find the "the HTMLQuestion schema URL"?

2) Do I generate the assignmentId or does it get inserted on the POST?

3) Is there something I need to add for CDATA is it is a placeholder for an array?

(Please forgive my ignorance but I may even being asking the wrong questions. I'm just not clear what to do next - especially to test it myself (sandbox). I tried posting in the Turk forum but no replies in two days. I don't expect the AWS manual to be for novices.)

```
<pre>
<HTMLQuestion xmlns="[the HTMLQuestion schema URL]">
  <HTMLContent><![CDATA[
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'/>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/mturk-public/externalHIT_v1.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name='mturk_form' method='post' id='mturk_form' action='https://www.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit'>
    <input type='hidden' value='' name='assignmentId' id='assignmentId'/>
     ... my handwritten form elements ...
</form>
  <script language='Javascript'>turkSetAssignmentID();</script>
 </body>
</html>
]]>
  </HTMLContent>
  <FrameHeight>0</FrameHeight>
</HTMLQuestion>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the latest link I found so far:

```
<HTMLQuestion xmlns="http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2011-11-11/HTMLQuestion.xsd">
```